# Did the FCC steal the Stack Overflow logo?

Tags: discussion, logo

I went to file my net-neutrality comments today, and look what I found:

[image: Screenshot]

It appears to be a "create PDF" button...

Comment: Related [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295769/250962)

Comment: Thanks - should I close this question, then?

Comment: i don't believe you can close as cross site duplicate or what close option would fit

Comment: It isn't theft, it's a tax.

Comment: The FCC isn't a taxing authority, so it must be a fine.